# What is the risk of not including all of my model predictors in an imputation process?

Tags: r, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I have a model that I want to run but a lot of my predictors have missing values. So I ran an imputation process using `mice` package in R - it took me 22.5 hours!

But, Alas! I forgot to include 4 variables which are part of the predictors for my model, in the imputation. Those 4 variables have very few missing values.

I don't want to perform the 22.5 hours imputation again, so my question is how bad is it if I include those 4 variables in the model (which now has the imputed variables) without them being part of the imputations process before?

Following a suggestion from the comments: I have 13,002 observations and around 530 variables in total.

Comment: You've given us very little basis for answering.  I suppose if these were 4 out of 100 predictors then it's very unlikely that excluding them would matter materially.  If 4 out of 7, much more likely.  And then if these 4 were particularly highly correlated with the rest, more likely still, since that would mean they would be  instrumental in imputing missing values.

Comment: @rolando2 I've edited the question, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You could test to see how much these four predictors matter.  Assess a few key relationships, both for currently imputed data and for a much smaller dataset (N ~ 1 or 2 thousand) whose imputation you conduct without the four predictors in question. If these key relationships hardly change, you'll have some additional basis for saying the exclusion didn't matter much -- to go along with the intuition that 526 predictors should perform very nearly as well as 530 for imputation.

I also wonder why you are working with 530 predictors, and whether, especially given your computer processing limits, you might benefit from winnowing them down -- using a priori reasons; data reduction techniques such as principal component analysis; or some sort of variable selection handled as part of a predictive model.  Of course, your strategy will be different if you are conducting a causal analysis as opposed to a predictive one.